# Image thresholding in LUA - LOVE

Tags: lua, love2d, image-thresholding

In order to only have only one input image for a "spread like" effect I would like to do some threshold operation on some drawable or to find any other way that work.

Are there any such tools in LOVE2d/Lua ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about the desired outcome, the "spread like" effect, but to create thresholding, you best use pixel shader something like this.

```
extern float threshold;    //external variable from our lua script

vec4 effect(vec4 color, Image tex, vec2 texture_coords, vec2 screen_coords)
{
    vec4 texturecolor = Texel(tex, texture_coords); //default shader code

    //get average color of pixel
    float average = (texturecolor[0] + texturecolor[1] + texturecolor[2])/3;
    //set alpha of pixel to 0 if average of RGB is below threshold
    if (average < threshold) {
        texturecolor[3] = 0;
    }

    return texturecolor * color;    //default shader code
}
```

This code calculates the average of RGB for each pixel and if the average is below threshold, it changes alpha of that pixel to 0 to make it invisible.

To use the pixel effect in your code you need to do something like this (only once, perhaps in `love.load`):

```
shader = love.graphics.newShader([==[ ... shader code above ... ]==])
```

and when drawing the image:

```
love.graphics.setShader(shader)
love.graphics.draw(img)
love.graphics.setShader()
```

To adjust the threshold:

```
shader:send("threshold", number)    --0 to 1 float
```

Result:

[image: result of drawing operation]

References:

- [LÖVE Shader object](https://love2d.org/wiki/Shader)
- [love.graphics.newShader](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newShader) for examples of the default shader code